# Rails 4: customize model ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I am currently following Jessica Biggs's *[Creating a Scoped Invitation System for Rails](https://coderwall.com/p/rqjjca/creating-a-scoped-invitation-system-for-rails)* codewall.com tutorial.

In the *Send Invitation Form* section, the author says:

> We'll also need a Mailer to send the email. The invitation mailer is
>   very basic, so I'm not going to go into a lot of detail here, but it
>   will send to the :email of the newly created invitation and include an
>   invite URL that we will construct later. The mailer will have 2
>   methods, one for sending he invitation email to new users and one for
>   sending a notification email to existing users.

Since I am not very experienced with Rails in general and ActionMailer in particular, I tried to understand what the author was saying from [Rails Guides Action Mailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html).

So, I ran `rails g mailer InviteMailer` to generate my mailer and added the following actions:

```
class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def invite_new_user
    @link = new_user_registration_path(:invite_token => @invite.token) 
    mail to: @invite.email, subject: "Calendar Invitation"
  end

  def notify_existing_user
  end

end
```

Now, I have hit a wall and I don't know how to move forward and implement the rest of the mailer.

Any hint pointing me in the right direct would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the link Max. This is actually the resource I am referring to in my  question when I say "Rails Guide". I am going to update it for more clarity. The problem is that I having a hard time translating the content of the quote into an actual Mailer, even using the documentation. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I missed the link in my first reading. That why I deleted the comment.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for taking the time to look at my question anyway ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so you have got your Mailer class and the methods.

> Mailers are very similar to Rails controllers. They also have methods
>   called `actions` and use `views` to structure the content. Where a
>   controller generates content like HTML to send back to the client, a
>   Mailer creates a message to be delivered via email.

Now, you need to define `notify_existing_user` action of your mailer, say you want to send an email to the existing user saying `Thanks for signing up!` So, you have to add:

```
class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'your_email@example.com'

  def notify_existing_user(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Thanks for signing up!')
  end
end
```

> `default` Hash - This is a hash of default values for any email you send
>   from this mailer.

So, you can use your email address there as the from email address.

Now, you need to create a Mailer View:

`notify_existing_user.html.erb` in `app/views/invite_mailer/`. This will be the template used for the email, formatted in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.name %></h1>
    <p>Thanks for signing up!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also create a text view  `notify_existing_user.text.erb` in `app/views/invite_mailer/`:

```
Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.name %>
===============================================

Thanks for signing up!
```

> Mailers are really just another way to render a view. Instead of
>   rendering a view and sending out the HTTP protocol, they are just
>   sending it out through the email protocols instead. Due to this, it
>   makes sense to just have your controller tell the Mailer to send an
>   email when a user is successfully created.

Let's create a simple User scaffold:

```
rails generate scaffold user name email login
rake db:migrate
```

Then, you can call the `InviteMailer.notify_existing_user` method from your `users_controller` like following:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        # Tell the InviteMailer to notify the existing user that just been created
        InviteMailer.notify_existing_user(@user).deliver_later

        format.html { redirect_to(@user, notice: 'User was successfully created.') }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

That's it. Now, when you create an user and when the user is saved, he will be sent an email using the `notify_existing_user` method of your `InviteMailer`.

Comment: Added the user argument to `notify_existing_user` otherwise it will just give a `Wrong number of arguments` error

Comment: @max, I wrote the answer quickly at the beginning and could not get the time to check. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your mailer needs to know what user it should be emailing. So we add a user argument. The rest is pretty simple: we just call mail which creates a mail object, it is implicitly returned.

```
class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def invite_new_user(user, invite)
    @user = user
    @invite = invite
    mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Welcome! ...')
  end

  def notify_existing_user(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Sorry to nag you ...')
  end  
end
```

`mail` will automatically look for the following templates and add them to the email body.

```
<%# app/views/invite_mailer/invite_new_user.html.erb %>
<h1>Your are cordially invited to ...</h1>
Add the invitation link here. The invitation is available as @invite.
```

---

```
<%# app/views/invite_mailer/notify_existing_user.html.erb %>
<h1>Yo dude ...</h1>
```

Note that if you want to send multipart plaintext / html emails you need to create a `.text.erb` view as well. Sending a plaintext version is usually a good idea.

To call our mailer we would do something like:

```
class InvitationsController 

  def new
     @user = User.new
  end

  def create
     @user = User.new(user_params) 
     @invite = Invitation.new
     # @todo generate some kind of invitation token.

     if @invite.save
       InviteMailer.invite_new_user(@user, @invitation).deliver_later
       redirect_to users_path, notice: 'invitation sent'
     else
       render :new
     end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email)
  end
end
```

Comment: This differs a bit from the tutorial but I hope you get the basic gist - Mailers are like controllers but for email. Mailer actions should return a mail object. Pass any needed dependencies into the action.